# Optaplanner - Drools for int array constraint

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm trying to write a constraint to check if any element of a integer array (binUsedArray) is greater than a bound (dailyMaxNb).

```
rule "BinResourceConstraint"
    when
        BinResource($array : binUsedArray, $dailyMaxNb : dailyMaxNb)
        $x : Integer() from $array
        $x > $dailyMaxNb
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

I read drools doc 5.1.8 and tried to write a similar rule like this

```
rule "Iterate the numbers"
when
    $xs : List()
    $x : Integer() from $xs
then
    $x matches and binds to each Integer in the collection
end
```

but got some error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=com/cttq/aps/solver/taskScheduleConstraint.drl, line=78, column=0
   text=[ERR 102] Line 78:11 mismatched input '>' in rule "BinResourceConstraint"], Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=com/cttq/aps/solver/taskScheduleConstraint.drl, line=0, column=0
   text=Parser returned a null Package]]
```

===== updated with BinResource class, `binUsedArray` is a int array with size of 30, to keep number of bins used for next 30 days.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class BinResource {
    private String index;
    private String binType;
    private String binArea;

    private int dailyMaxNb;

    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerRef = @PlanningVariableReference(entityClass = TaskAssignment.class, variableName = "modifiedProcessTimeInShift"))
    private int[] binUsedArray;
```

Comment: To clarify -- `binUsedArray` is `int[]` or `Integer[]` and you want to see if any value in that array is `> $dailyMaxNb`?

Comment: The second rule works for collections. An array is not a java.util.Collection, so it makes sense you can't use the identical workflow for your `int[]`/`Integer[]`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas binUsedArray is int[] and yes, I want to check every value in this array.

Answer (score 1):

The trivial solution would be to convert your array to a List and then it'll just work. `Arrays.asList( array )` can be invoked on the LHS to convert the array ... something like:

```
BinResource($array : binUsedArray, $dailyMaxNb : dailyMaxNb)
$binUsed: List() from Arrays.asList($array)
```

Then you can do the same logic from the second rule to find the values which meet your criteria:

```
$x : Integer(this > $dailyMaxNb) from $binUsed
```

With that, your rule will trigger once for each value (`$x`) in the array / list which is greater than the `dailyMaxNb` value.

```
rule "BinResourceConstraint"
when
  BinResource($array : binUsedArray, $dailyMaxNb : dailyMaxNb)
  $binUsed: List() from Arrays.asList($array)
  $x : Integer(this > $dailyMaxNb) from $binUsed
then
  // this will trigger once PER MATCH ... 
  // eg if there are 3 values that > dailyMaxNb, this will trigger 3 times
  scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end
```

If, however, your `binUsedArray` is actually an `ArrayList`, you can omit the conversion and just use `$x: Integer(this > $dailyMaxNb) from $array`. I mention this because sometimes when people ask about an "array" they're actually referring to an array list, and you've not provided the code of your BinResource class. That being said, you can use this pattern (`MyType( <condition> ) from $collection`) for any iterable collection to attempt to match against all values in that collection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and detailed replay. I'll try to convert to list array instead. Also I tried to write a custom function in helper class and it seemed work.